# Visual Studio Code Azure Function Error as The term 'func' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions

I am trying to create Azure Functions with Typescript in Visual Studio code. When i run the code it throws an error.

"The term 'func' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the

spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again".

I have installed npm, Azure tools. Could you please help me.

Am running the type script azure function under local user access.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I have created function with runtime stack Typescript in VS Code.
Below commands are used to create function

Uninstall the current azure function core tools and download latest by using below command.

```
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true

func init MyFunctionApp --typescript
cd MyFunctionApp
func new
```

I took http trigger function.

**host.json:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

By using `func start` command executed function successfully.
check below:

[image]

Comment: Are you running it as an administrator

Comment: @Nagarajan No, I ran in vs code terminal only and also I ran as an administrator also it worked like mentioned above.